# Determine bounding rect of line in Qt

Tags: qt, line, bounding-box, qpainter

I am drawing a line using `QPainterPath` between two points as follows:

```
QPainterPath line;
line.moveTo(start_p);
line.lineTo(end_p);

QPen paintpen(Qt::black);
paintpen.setWidth(1);
painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
painter->setBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
painter->setPen(paintpen);
painter->drawPath(line);
```

I have defined bounding rect as:

```
QRectF Line::boundingRect() const
{
 return QRectF(start_p.x(), start_p.y(), end_p.x(), end_p.y());
}
```

I get line painted correctly when:

```
start_p.x() < end_p.x()
```

and

```
start_p.y() < end_p.y()
```

How should the bounding rect be defined so that line is drawn correctly irrespective of the relationship between the coordinates of two points(start_p and end_p)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try to normalize your rectangle:

```
QRectF Line::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(start_p.x(), start_p.y(), end_p.x(), end_p.y()).normalized();
}
```

Comment: The arguments to this version of QRectF's constructor (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html#QRectF-3) are x, y, width, and height. Shouldn't it be `QRectF(start_p, end_p)` (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html#QRectF-2)?

Comment: @Mitch, right, it might be `QRectF(start_p, end_p)` too.

Answer (score 3):

You could either:-

- Check for the conditions when the ends are greater than the start points and set the rect appropriately
- Return the QPainterPath's bounding rect
- Use a [QGraphicsLineItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicslineitem.html) instead of reinventing the wheel.

If you just want a line, [QGraphicsLineItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicslineitem.html) is likely the best way to go here.

Comment: The third one is the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QPainterPath::boundingRect` which returns the bounding rectangle of the `QPainterPath`. You can keep the painter path as a class member and access it in the `boundingRect` function :

```
QRectF Line::boundingRect() const
{
     return line.boundingRect();
}
```